# Convert escaped unicode sequence to Emoji in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, emoji

I have a string in JS as follows. I am having a hard time converting these surrogate pairs to emoji's. Can someone help?

I have tried to get a solution online by searching almost everything that I could, but in vain.

```
var text = 'CONGRATS! Your task has been completed! Tell us how we did \\uD83D\\uDE4C \\uD83D\\uDC4D \\uD83D\\uDC4E'
```

This is a node.js code. Is there any easy way to convert these codes to emojis without using an external helper utility?

EDIT:

I updated my code and the regex as follows:

```
var text = 'CONGRATS! Your task has been completed! Tell us how we did {2722} {1F44D} {1F44E}';

text.replace(/\{[^}]*\}/ig, (_, g) => String.fromCodePoint(`0x${g}`))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to replace all Unicode escape sequences with their HEX representations and use `String.fromCharCode()` to replace it with its associated character:

```js
const text = 'CONGRATS! Your task has been completed! Tell us how we did \\uD83D\\uDE4C \\uD83D\\uDC4D \\uD83D\\uDC4E';
const res = text.replace(/\\u([0-9A-F]{4})/ig, (_, g) => String.fromCharCode(`0x${g}`));

console.log(res);
```

As for your edit, your issue is with your regular expression. You can change it to be `/\{([^}]*)\}/g`, which means:

1. `\{` - match an open curly brace.
2. `([^}]*)` - match and *group* the contents after the open curly brace which is not a closed curly brace `}`.
3. `}` - match a closed curly brace.
4. `g` - match the expression globally (so all occurrences of the expression, not just the first)

The entire regular expression will match `{CONTENTS}`, whereas the group will contain only the contents between the two curly braces, so `CONTENTS`. The match is the first argument provided to the `.replace()` callback function whereas the group (`g`) is provided as the second argument and is what we use:

```js
const text = 'CONGRATS! Your task has been completed! Tell us how we did {2722} {1F44D} {1F44E}';

const res = text.replace(/\{([^}]*)\}/g, (_, g) => String.fromCodePoint(`0x${g}`));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @nick-parsons. This helped me a lot.

Comment: this somehow appears as chinese symbols in an SMS, however looks correct in a JS console. Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Comment: @Shambhavi hm, not too sure. It depends on how you are sending the SMS I guess

Comment: @Shambhavi sure, I've provided an explanation in my answer (see edit)